# Unable to update theme font of wordpress theme 'the mysterious girl'

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, themes, font-family

Tried Theme Options > Style Settings > Font Settings (no change)

Tried Theme Options > Misc > General > Custom CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rochester'); 

body p {
  font-family: 'Rochester', cursive !important;
}
```

Not working at all it's giving me cursive fallback!

Worst thing they do not offer support. I didn't see that when buying theme!

Comment: hi try this --  https://wpsites.net/web-design/custom-fonts-wordpress-font-face-generator/   hope this works

Comment: one more http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-fonts-in-wordpress/

Comment: Awesome, you know what, I am not a PHP programmer but using the first tutorial you listed I tried to workout the wp_enqueue_style and it worked right away! Really awesome!